# syntax error, unexpected 'UNION' (T_STRING) union in query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "(Select max(bid),min(bid),max(ask),min(ask) From data Where date Between ('2017-05-12 09:06:00') AND ('2017-05-12 09:07:00')) UNION (select bid,ask from data order by date asc limit 1 )"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql)

if($result->num_rows>0)

 {

     while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
     {

        echo "max bid:".$row["max(bid)"]. "max ask:".$row["max(ask)"].  "min bid".$row["min(bid)"]. "min ask".$row["min(ask)"]. "<br>" ;
        echo "open bid" .$row["bid"]. "open ask" .$row["ask"];
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's usually better to do queries of the form `$conn->query("...")` with the string specified directly than to use a throw-away variable. Those can easily get mixed up, confused, or inadvertently re-run later because of a naming slip.

Comment: Have you tried a query in the form `SELECT ... UNION ...` with no braces around the front portion?

Answer (score 2):

I notice two things in your code.

```
1/ The column count is not same in the 2 select statements.

2/ $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

And Keep in mind the below conditions while using `UNION` operator.

The column names from the first `SELECT` statement are used as the column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each `SELECT` statement should have the same data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have the same type as the first column selected by the other statements.)

If the data types of corresponding `SELECT` columns do not match, the types and lengths of the columns in the `UNION` result take into account the values retrieved by all of the `SELECT` statements.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)